# Evaluate Dimension of $null space\cap range space$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

If $$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 0 \\
-1 &5 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$ and $$B=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
-1 & 0 \\
3 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$ $N(A)$ the null space of $A$ and $R(B)$ the range space of $B$ then evaluate dimension of $N(A)\cap R(B)$.

Obviously by reducing the matrices we will get $rank(A)=2$ and $rank(B)=2$ and therefore we will get dimension of $N(A)$ is 1.

But still dimension of $dim(N(A)+R(B))$ is needed to use the formula $dim(N(A)+R(B))=dimN(A)+ dimR(B)-dim(N(A)\cap R(B))$.

This question came in jam numerical answer type question. So there must be something to evaluate the answer..